# Objects not found in OpenCV4

Tags: c++, opencv

- This is my dir tree (root dir is `untitled`)

  [image]
- This is the content of `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package (OpenCV 4.5.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories ("/usr/local/include/opencv4/")

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

- This is my code in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    Mat color = imread("./lenna.png");
    Mat gray = imread("./lenna.png", 0);

    imwrite("./lennaGray.png", gray);

    int myRow = color.cols - 1;
    int myCol = color.rows - 1;

    Vec3b pixel = color.at<Vec3b>(myRow, myCol);

    cout << "Pixel value (B, G, R): (" << (int)pixel[0] << ", " << (int)pixel[1] << ", " << (int)pixel[2] << ")" << endl;

    imshow("Lenna BGR", color);
    imshow("Lenna Gray", gray);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

- This is the entire error when I ran `make` command:
  [image]
- But if I ran my code in terminal by this command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 && ./main
```

then it worked.
[image]

I don't know what happened, I just learned OpenCV and I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and OpenCV-4.5.2.

Comment: You did not tell CMake to link to opencv. You need to call `target_link_libraries()`

Comment: @drescherjm I already did it in the cmake file.

Comment: You did not do that in the `CMakeLists.txt` file you are showing. If you are missing some lines from your copy and paste please fix that and show your `target_link_libraries()`

Comment: @drescherjm so what parameters should I put in this statement. I followed this video to make my CMake file [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9pbdFSTGVI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9pbdFSTGVI)

Comment: I have to leave now so I will let others help. I found this old answer but not sure if it is correct with opencv4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726167/487892

Comment: How do you know the tutorial is telling you to do the right things?

Comment: you have to add opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs in your linker settings in the CmakeLists file. Since you already have used find_package you can just do: `target_link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS}) `