# OpenCV c++: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, apple-m1

Hi I am trying to get opencv to work on my m1 mac.

I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
```

This is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(){
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("hej.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(OpenCV_DIR "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable(test main.cpp)
```

Would really appriciate some help! I have read people getting OpenCV to work on M1 but dont know how.

Comment: You didn't link with the opencv libraries in your CMakeLists.txt. You should have a `target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})`

Comment: oh ok thanks! how should I do that?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691912/linking-opencv-in-a-project-using-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691912/linking-opencv-in-a-project-using-cmake)