# Cannot open source file error with vcpkg on vscode mac

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

I'm trying to use external libraries (specifically opencv) with C++ but I'm having some trouble. It seems like using vcpkg is the easiest way to go about this. So far I've followed these tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7SdgK7Y510 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZeK3Ie5Fz0 but I keep getting these errors when I try to include a file:

cannot open source file "opencv2/core.hpp"

'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found

The quick fix provided by vscode says to install opencv through vcpkg but I've already done that. I've linked vcpkg according to the tutorials and included the path to the cmake toolchain file in my settings.json file.

Here is the change I made to my settings.json file:

```
{
"cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "/Users/oliverpasquesi/coding/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
}
```

}

Here is the CMakeLists.txt file (it is the same as the one from the 2nd tutorial listed):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(photoText.cpp VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(photoText.cpp main.cpp)
```

Here is the includePath portion of the c_cpp_properties.json file (including the 2nd path doesn't make any difference in the errors being thrown):

```
"includePath": [
            "${default}",
            "/Users/oliverpasquesi/coding/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/opencv2/**"
        ]
```

If it's useful, I'm using vscode 1.49.2 on a mac running Darwin x64 21.5.0.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You say that you have done all the right things, and yet it doesn't work. Therefore you should post the settings files you have changed so someone here can check whether you have done the right thing. I'm really not sure why this needs to be explained.

Comment: Are you using the CMakeTools Extension for VSCode?

Comment: @drescherjm yes I am. I made an edit to the post with the changes I made in the settings.json file

Comment: @john I made some changes to show the changes I made to the settings.json file.

Comment: @OliP14 Have you made any other changes? I'm not seeing anything where you have told VSCode where the opencv files are installed.

Comment: @OliP14 Normally with CMake when you wish to use a third party library you would edit a file called CMakeLists.txt. Have you done that? (I'm no expert on CMake though).

Comment: @john I've changed the post to include my CMakeLists.txt file. It is the same as the one from the 2nd tutorial I followed. I've seen in some places where people add the path the the include files from the library in the includePath in c_cpp_properties.json but when I did that, it didn't make any difference. Regardless, I've also included what I previously had in my includePath section of c_cpp_properties.json file.

Comment: @OliP14 Well that seems to be the problem. Your  CMakeLists.txt file contains no reference to opencv so that's why the compilation fails. Here's how it should look https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html (this is from the official opencv documentation).

Comment: These are the three lines that tell Cmake about opencv `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )` and 
`include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )` and
`target_link_libraries( photoText.cpp ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`

Comment: Hmm the errors still persist... Another error popped up when I added those to the CMakeLists.txt file saying: The imported target "opencv_core" references the file "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.4.5.5.dylib" but this file does not exist. It gives some possible reasons for this saying it could have been deleted, renamed, or moved, the install or uninstall didn't complete correctly, or the installation package was faulty and contained "/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake" but not all the files it references.

Comment: The only thing is though, how this have gone wrong if I used vcpkg to install opencv. Maybe should I try uninstalling opencv and reinstalling it?

Comment: @OliP14 There's another way to approach this, maybe you would find it easier, and a better learning experience. You are trying to throw lots of tools at the problem of writing C++ code, vcpkg, CMake, VSCode etc. These tools abstract away any direct interaction with the compiler. This has it's merits but the problem for beginners is that when things go wrong they are left clueless because they have no idea how anything works 'under the hood'. Plus all these tools inevitably add complexity, especially when the have to interact with each another.

Comment: @OliP14 The other simpler way is just to use the compiler directly. Open a terminal windows and type the appropriate commands to invoke the compiler. Obviously this is a skill that you have to learn, but I promise it's more straightforward than what you are attempting now.

Comment: @OliP14 Now you don't have to do this for ever. Spend a few week building your programs like this, until you have gained some familiarity with how your compiler works. Then add CMake to your build. Now you may find you like CMake or your may find you preferred things as they were. But the main point is that because you understand your compiler, you will have a better understanding of what CMake is asking from you, and what is happening when things go wrong.

Comment: @OliP14 Now spend a few week with CMake until you are comfortable, then add VSCode into the mix. What I'm saying in essence is that you should learn one thing at a time and build up from the basic to advanced. You have a much deeper understanding that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference your library in the CMakeLists.txt file as well, since that's the file CMake uses to prepare your project for a build.

A modern way to do this is to add two lines:

1. A find_package() line to find the libraries you are using. As you already referenced the vcpkg.cmake toolchain file, CMake should be able to find any libraries already installed by vcpkg when you add that line. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html for documentation.
2. A target_link_libraries() line that lists libraries to link against your project. See the CMake documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

As you are using the opencv library, you may want to look at the answers to this question as well: [Linking Opencv in a project using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691912/linking-opencv-in-a-project-using-cmake)

Specifically, try adding these lines to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(photoText.cpp ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

vcpkg documentation on its CMake integration (for additional reference): https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration.html

Hopefully this helps!

Disclaimer: I work on the vcpkg tool.

Comment: I've added those 2 functions into the CMakeLists.txt file but there are still errors the same. Is there anything else I should be doing/including?

Comment: @OliP14 The first question you must ask yourself is does the file mentioned `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.4.5.5.dylib` actually exist? If not does a similar file exist, maybe a different version number, or a different extension, or maybe in a different location. You have to investigate/diagnose your problems, it's not enough just to quote error messages.